# how to work a flash file that has over 16,000 frames?

Tags: flash

im planning to create a movie file that might have over 16,000 frames?i know this sounds silly but,i have already created 14 scenes which is just over 15,500.i have created the 15th scene but it stopped playing because i know maximum number of frame we can have is 16,000. is there any way around this problem? its a huge presentation im doin and there is loads of stuff going in it.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very basic method in as2 :

- make one swf per scene. name them like scene_1.swf, scene_2.swf etc
- create an empty swf (same size as your scenes)

First frame of your empty swf :

```
function loadScene(scene_str) {
 loadMovieNum(scene_str,1);
}
```

Second frame :

```
loadScene('scene_1.swf');
stop();
```

Last frame of each scene :

```
_level0.loadScene( 'filename_of_the_next_scene.swf');
```

Answer (score 1):

break your scenes into separte movies

Comment: @ctrlShiftBryan:do i break them into separate movie clips or separate swf files? which one do you think is the ideal way?

Comment: Neither is better than the other -- do whichever one makes sense in your application.